# Chapter with specific number (1, 1b, 2, 2b, 3, 4)

Tags: numbering, chapters

Currently I use a manually declared version of the chapter title. But the idea is to extend it to use specific and manually chosen number of the chapters.

I try to obtain numbers like this `1, 1b, 2, 2b, 3, 4`. But for obtaining `b`, I want to specify it manually with for example an option in the `\chapter` command (something like this `\chapter{...}` for obtaining `1` then `\chapter[b]{...}` for obtaining `1b`.

Do you have any ideas for obtaining this result?

Comment: You could specify *all* of the manually. Just add `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{<whatever>}` before `\chapter{<title>}`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a `+` specifier for the “repeat chapters”; the proposed code doesn't interfere with usages of `\chapter*`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{repchapter}
\let\latex@chapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar{\latex@chapter*}{\guuk@chapter}}
\newcommand{\guuk@chapter}{\@ifnextchar+{\repeat@chapter}{\restore@chapter\latex@chapter}}
\newcommand{\repeat@chapter}[1]{% #1 is +
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
  \addtocounter{repchapter}{1}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}\alph{repchapter}}%
  \latex@chapter
}
\newcommand{\restore@chapter}{%
  \setcounter{repchapter}{1}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title}
x
\chapter+{Repeat}
x
\chapter{Title}
x
\chapter+{Repeat}
x
\chapter+{Again}
x
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you load `hyperref`, then add

```
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\thechapter}
```

just after `\makeatletter`. Make sure `\usepackage{hyperref}` is *before* the shown code.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Great! You always have a solution :-) I will try this.