# Cont. Dividing chapters into ch. 1, ch. 2a, ch. 2b, ch. 3 etc

Tags: chapters

I want to divide my chapters into sub chapters in same fashion as described in this question:
[Dividing chapters into ch. 1, ch. 2a, ch. 2b, ch. 3 etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111845/dividing-chapters-into-ch-1-ch-2a-ch-2b-ch-3-etc)

However I am not getting correct results. while Chapter name/counts are fine, subsections are incorrectly numbered.

Consider the modified file as provided in the accepted answer to above question:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
%\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\newcounter{subchapter}\renewcommand{\thesubchapter}{\alph{subchapter}}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\newcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\@afterheading}{\updatechaptercounter\@afterheading}{}{}% Regular patch of \@chapter
%\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}{\@afterheading}{\updatechaptercounter\@afterheading}{}{}% Hyperref patch of \@chapter
\makeatother
\providecommand{\theHchapter}{}%
\newcommand{\startsubchapters}{%
  \setcounter{subchapter}{0}% Reset sub-chapter numbering
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thesubchapter}% Update chapter number display
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thesubchapter}% Update chapter number display (for hyperref)
  \renewcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}}% Update chapter number
  \let\oldchapter\chapter%
  \renewcommand{\chapter}{\stepcounter{subchapter}\oldchapter}% Increment subchapter
}
\newcommand{\stopsubchapters}{%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% Reset chapter numbering
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}}% Reset chapter numbering (for hyperref)
  \let\chapter\oldchapter% Restore regular \chapter command
  \renewcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{}% Clear chapter counter update
  \stepcounter{chapter}% Update chapter counter
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{one one}
\section{one two}
\startsubchapters
\chapter{Second sub-chapter}
\section{2 A one}
\section{2 A two}
\chapter{Second sub-chapter}
\section{2 B one}
\section{2 B two}

\stopsubchapters
\chapter{Third chapter}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}
\end{document}
```

(I just added sections nothing more)

Provides me with following output:
[image: content page]
It should be section 2A.1, 2B.1 etc. instead of 1A.1 1B.1 etc.
What am I doing wrong?

(compiled using pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX), on windows)

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  in your definition of `\startsubchapters` you have the command `\let\oldchapter\chapter%` (you don't need the `%`, by the way).  that should only happen on subchapters after the first, since the first in a group really should step the chapter counter.  you might set a switch to indicate whether the first in a group has been processed yet; such a switch can be turned off at `\stopsubchapters`.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229068/appending-alphanumeric-character-to-chapter-numbers has better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

examine your definition of `\startsubchapter`:

```
\newcommand{\startsubchapters}{%
  \setcounter{subchapter}{0}% Reset sub-chapter numbering
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thesubchapter}% Update chapter number display
  \renewcommand{\theHchapter}{\arabic{chapter}\thesubchapter}% Update chapter number display (for hyperref)
  \renewcommand{\updatechaptercounter}{\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}}% Update chapter number
  \let\oldchapter\chapter%
  \renewcommand{\chapter}{\stepcounter{subchapter}\oldchapter}% Increment subchapter
}
```

the first time the redefined `\chapter` is used, it will have the value of the
previous chapter, and furthermore, that will never change.  the chapter counter
does need to be stepped -- just once -- when you start the group of subchapters.

this can be accomplished by using a switch to indicate a new group, like this,
for example:

```
\newif\iffirstsubchapter
\firstsubchaptertrue
```

then add some code to use it just before setting up `\oldchapter`:

```
  \iffirstsubchapter
    \firstsubchapterfalse
  \fi
  \let\oldchapter\chapter
```

finally, add a reversal to the definition of `\stopsubchapters`:

```
  \firstsubchaptertrue
```

that can go anywhere in the definition.  (i'd put it as the last thing.)